# Java stream forEach

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, stream, java-stream

I'm trying to read a .CSV line by line using streams and forEach, but I can't make it work properly.

```
public static void printFile(String file)
{
    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file)))
    {
        stream
            .filter(line -> line.startsWith("00"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Facturation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

"file" here is my .CSV absolute path. I tried my best repairing this code but I keep getting the same error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
>       at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:574)
>       at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1811)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>       at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findAny(ReferencePipeline.java:469)
>       at facturation.Facturation.factureFile(Facturation.java:65)
>       at facturation.Facturation.main(Facturation.java:43)

Line 43 is the call to my function printFile and line 65 is the .forEach.

So my question is quite simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: File might have invalid text other than UTF-8 characters

Comment: `Files.lines` defaults to `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: Yup, this is likely to be an encoding problem.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth, sorry indeed that was a **stupid** thing to say :)

Comment: @RealSkeptik Thank you, the answer to the question you marked as duplicate worked for me! It was indeed an encoding error.